# How to redefine an Active User on Google Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

How do I redefine the definition of an "Active User" on Firebase Analytics? I would like to exclude first-time users that have only signed-up, but have not used the core functionality of the app (completing a core action). Currently, Firebase is including first-time sign-ups which skews our retention and conversion data.

This is for a fitness app that is developed using React Native and uses Firebase as backend. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it might be useful for you to explore the concept of [audiences](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267572), since you could group the users that you consider relevant based on an [event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=web) (e.g. complete the core action that you define) or a certain condition is met given that you set a particular [user property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties?platform=web#set_user_properties_3) (e.g. `firebase.analytics().setUserProperties({completed_core_action: "True"});`) on your application.